# NullPointerException at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.getLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:108)

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

We are getting `NullPointerException` in `org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.getLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:108)` when using hibernate3 with heavy load on our Web Application. We are using separate hibernate `Session` for each request (Thread).

`StatefulPersistenceContext.getEntry()` is returning null at above point.

See Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.getLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:108)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:1003)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:646)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:591)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
at com.sibisoft.northstar.events.service.EventReservationService.getReservationsByEventId(EventReservationService.java:1075)
at com.sibisoft.northstar.events.service.EventSeatingService.getGuestCountsGroupBySchedule(EventSeatingService.java:832)...
```

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to [the latest hibernate3 version](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.10.Final)?

Comment: I am not sure that this error exists in later version or not.

Comment: What version are you using, anyway?

Comment: @lifus We are using Hibernate-Version: 3.2.6.ga

Comment: There are a number of bug fixes since then. e.g. [this one](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6/changelog.txt#L1340). Anyway, error occurs when hibernate is trying to `getStatus` of [null](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.6.ga/org/hibernate/engine/loading/CollectionLoadContext.java#109)